# Laravel 4: Can't get model data with a form macro on edit form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

On edit forms I have a problem to populate form fields with data stored in DB.

When I use the code snippet from the doc everything's fine. However I need to append a css class to the form field, and this cannot be passed as argument for:

```
{{ Form::text('email') }}
```

So I've created the below Form::macro

```
Form::macro('textclass', function($name, $class = null)
{
    return '<input type="text" name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'" class="'.$class.'"/>';
});
```

So I can use this on my views:

```
{{ Form::textclass('email', 'm-wrap span12') }}
```

But then the field doesn't get populated with the model data.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You can pass options to the text method like this `Form::text('email',null,array('class'=>'m-wrap span12))` . The third parameter accepts array with options for the text input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference if you want to check what the `Form` generates you can look up `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder`.

In the `FormBuilder` class you'll find methods for the inputs. The method for the text input looks like this

```
 public function text($name, $value = null, $options = array())
 {
    return $this->input('text', $name, $value, $options);
 }
```

As you can see the second parameter is the value and the third is the options array.

So for your form it would look like this

`Form::text('email', null, array('class'=>'m-wrap span12'))`

Comment: Should prolly edit the answer the include the code you posted as comment, just for future reference.